# How to add click listener to dynamically added button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding a button dynamically by doing:

```
<input id="{Id}" type="submit" value="View">
```

`{Id}` is replaced at runtime with the record id.

I would like to have a function like:

```
function viewRecord(button) {
    //Do something here...
}
```

How can I add a click listener to the button that corresponds to the correct button being clicked?

I've started learning `jquery` today and would like an answer that shows how it's implemented.

**EDIT**

Based on the answer below, I'm trying the following:

```
<td><input class="viewRecord" type="submit" value="View"></td>

$(".viewRecord").click(function () {
    var $table = $('#table'),
    var $tableBody = $table.find('tbody'),
    var $text = $tableBody.closest('tr').attr('id');

    alert($text);
});
```

However, no alert is being displayed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: "replaced at runtime" by what?  Can that same code also add the code for the handler?  Can you create a handler on `document` and filter by `id` values?  It seems like there's more to this than we're seeing.

Comment: Why not using class?

Comment: you can make a common function which takes in one parameter as the `ID` of that respective element and performs different operation based on the ID, then bind `onclick='function(this.id)'` to the input.  Dynamically they can be injected by the `setAttribute` method to be called upon the element.

Answer (score 1):

use following code:

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="{Id}" type="submit" value="View" class="dynamic-btn" />
</div>

(function($) {
    var btnClick = function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
        /*Do smth that you needed*/
    };

    $(function() {
        $("#container").on("click", ".dynamic-btn", btnClick)
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: How can I pass the `id` from the row as a parameter to the function?

Answer (score 1):

**Two steps:**

1) Find the `input` with:

```
var dynamicButton = document.getElementById('{Id}');
```

2) Add the `click` Event Listener with:

```
dynamicButton.addEventListener('click',function(){viewRecord(dynamicButton.id);},false);
```